# how can i correct line errors in views?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Need some assistance with how to turn 'on' error lines (Oracle SQL Developer) in order to properly identify where this error is in order to correct.
[Image of current problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZNop.png)

Looked under Tools -> Preferences and went through them and didn't locate how to turn the error lines on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the line numbers in the worksheet, open the preferences and then in the panel on the left expand "Code Editor". In that section select "Line Dutter". The panel for that has an option labelled "Show Line Numbers". Tick that box and click "OK".

[image: SQL Developer preferences]

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle SQL Developer, you can turn on error highlighting for SQL statements by going to "Tools" > "Preferences" and then navigating to "Editor" > "SQL Editor" > "Syntax Coloring". In the "Syntax Coloring" window, you can select the "Error" category in the list on the left, and then choose a color for the error highlighting in the "Color" field on the right.

Alternatively, you can turn on error highlighting by selecting a SQL statement and then going to "Format" > "Syntax Coloring" > "Error".

To turn on line numbers in the SQL editor, go to "Tools" > "Preferences" and then navigate to "Editor" > "SQL Editor". In the "SQL Editor" preferences window, you can check the "Line Numbers" option to display line numbers in the SQL editor.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To turn on error lines in Oracle SQL Developer, follow these steps:

1. Go to the "View" menu and select "DBMS Output". This will open the
   DBMS Output pane at the bottom of the SQL Developer window.
2. In the DBMS Output pane, click the "Settings" button (it looks like a gear).
3. In the "DBMS Output" settings window, select the "Error Stack" tab.
4. Check the box next to "Show error stack on error" to turn on error lines.
5. Click "OK" to apply the changes and close the settings window.

With error lines turned on, when you encounter an error in your SQL code, the error message will include the line number and file name where the error occurred. This can help you identify the location of the error and make it easier to correct.

I hope this helps!